# migrating phonebook/contacts after Cyanogen mod install

Tags: cyanogenmod, contacts

Trying to find a straight answer - I have 3 year old Samsung SCI 1500 and am tired of bloatware, most of which just tracks me.  I have backed up the phone with ADB.  I'd like to root it and install Cyanogen, I know this wipes data.  It appears CM does include a phonebook/contact function, is there a way to populate it with the contact info from my ADB backup?  Can't seem to find that answer anywhere.  I don't want my address list on google.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest, in parallel to your ADB backup, to consider some additional [backup](/questions/tagged/backup) strategies – especially in the context of "moving to more privacy":

- Use the apps' own backup features. For the contacts app, this would be the Import/Export item in the menu appearing when you hit the menu key. As the name suggests, the export created here can be imported at the very same place on your CMified device.
- Consider other specialized backup apps (no need for contacts, as above export will be fine) for things like your calendar data, WiFi passwords, etc.
- Consider [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) for almost everything. This app for one has a "migration mode" for later restore on a different ROM, and also supports XML backups for different system data (e.g. WiFi passwords).

When going CM, you will certainly install a custom recovery (such as [clockworkmod](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod) or [twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp)) as well. Consider making a [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) backup right after that (and before installing CM), so you have an "image" of your complete system.

For your later restore, and if you want to avoid the *GApps*, again [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) comes in handy. I strongly recommend the Pro version, and buying it directly at the dev's site – as that way it will stay "Pro" even without GApps&Play. It can not only read its own backups, but above mentioned Nandroid and ADB backups as well, so you could pick even single things from them which you might have forgotten to backup separately.

Last hint: If you're looking for a GApps replacement, check [NOGAPPS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1715375). Not yet fully ready, but looks quite promising.

Now, good luck on your way to freedom :)